# All circle counter showing same data (how to make each circle show it's own counter data value)

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter

hwllo i want my circle counters to display counter value as i mention in their class and **data-percent**
but currently all 4 counters are shwoing the data of 1st counter only however i have mentioned the data-percent value of each counter in its html code.
please help me figure out what's wrong and what should i do to make it correct?
any help is appreciated and code is provided for clear understanding:

the code used below is showing me this result as shown in the picture:

[image]

currently i'm using this js code snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
  var bar, c, percent, r, range;

  percent = $('.pie').data('percent');

  bar = $('.pie').find('.bar');

  r = bar.attr('r');

  c = Math.PI * (r * 2);

  range = (100 - percent) / 100 * c;

  bar.css({
    'stroke-dashoffset': c,
    'stroke-dasharray': c });


  bar.animate({
    strokeDashoffset: range },
  1000, 'linear');

  $('.text').prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: percent },
  {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function (now) {
      return $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
    } });


}).call(this);
</script>
```

and html is this:

```
<!--counter new -->
<div class="container-fluid counter"> 
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3">

<div class="svg-box"><span class="text">0%</span>
  <svg class="pie" viewbox="0 0 200 200" data-percent="99">
    <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
    <circle class="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">

<div class="svg-box"><span class="text">0%</span>
  <svg class="pie" viewbox="0 0 200 200" data-percent="32">
    <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
    <circle class="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">

<div class="svg-box"><span class="text">0%</span>
  <svg class="pie" viewbox="0 0 200 200" data-percent="44">
    <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
    <circle class="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">

<div class="svg-box"><span class="text">0%</span>
  <svg class="pie" viewbox="0 0 200 200" data-percent="22">
    <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
    <circle class="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--counter new end -->
```

the css used is also shown below:

```
.svg-box {
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: "Raleway", Calibri, sans-serif;
  color: #fff
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  fill: none;
}
svg circle {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: #999;
}
svg .bar {
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

i want to display the counters by showing the

> "data-percent" vale

whihc i've mentioned in the html code. but all the counters are showing the data value of 1st counter.

how ever what i want to display *data* is like this:
[image]

Comment: Please add all the relevant codes, running your code only shows the circle animation. Is there a jquery ui for this?

Comment: @Gosi this is all the code i used for animation, all css , html and js is provided

Comment: I tried running this on jsfiddle, but only got the outline circle. can't produce the same as your image. you must be missing some link to the js or css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've redesigned a little your code, and I think it should work correctly.

```
(function () {

 $('.pie').each(function(){

 let percent = $(this).data('percent');
 let bar = $(this).find('.bar');
 let r = bar.attr('r');
 let c = Math.PI * (r * 2);
 let range = (100 - percent) / 100 * c;
 bar.css({
  'stroke-dashoffset': c,
  'stroke-dasharray': c 
 });
 bar.animate({ strokeDashoffset: range }, 1000, 'linear');

$(this).prev().prop('Counter', 0).animate({ 
    Counter: percent 
  },                                 {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function (now) {
      return $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
    }
  });  
 })
}).call(this);
```

And here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w2o7rt1L/